# Cancel Reporting Services report

Tags: wcf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My company has a webservice that calls the MS Reporting Services ReportExecutionService (ReportExecution2005.asmx)

We we want to be able to cancel a report from the UI, but this needs to be done in such a way that the server stops processing the report (because the report may be resource-intensive, and we want to conserve our load if we can).

Unfortunately, I can't find a clean way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want using the RS web service. This blog post highlights some issues with cancelling long running reports and also has a couple of workarounds:

http://mystuffisallhere.com/blog/post/2010/01/26/SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-2005-and-2008-e28093-cancelling-a-long-running-report-causes-the-next-e2809cView-reporte2809d-to-hang-the-UI-until-the-original-finishes.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but this does not actually answer my question. The article you are referencing concerns a particular implementation of a ReportViewer, and it's actually not the one I'm using. Not that it is relevant, but I'm using PerpetuumSoft's ReportViewer for Silverlight.

I am actually just trying to figure out if there's a way to cancel the report on the server.

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have expanded on that article a bit more. It's not directly relevant to what you want to do but the author is running into the same issue, which is that the reporting services "cancel" function only cancels report processes running on the report server. It does not cancel any queries that have been executed, these are left to run to completion as "orphaned" queries. There is no way to cancel these queries through reporting services itself, they must normally be cancelled manually.

Comment: The only approach that I am aware of to mitigate this is to set query timeout options for report datasets. There is more background on the cancellation functionality of Reporting Services here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156304.aspx

Comment: Since it's been a long time since I posted this and I haven't gotten any other answers that explain how to actually answer everything, I'm going to assume that this is the best possible answer.

Thanks Nathan.